# How can we find the memory usage in marklogic using query?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How can we find the memory consumption in our Marklogic environment? The memory which is used the the documents?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. Are you referring to the memory used by MarkLogic server for a running instance, or the amount of memory consumed to service a query, or what?

Comment: I want to know if there is a query/xdmp function which can be used to find out the memory used by the Marklogic server?

Answer (score 0):

The default error log should help you:

> With the release of MarkLogic Server versions 8.0-8 and 9.0-4,
> detailing memory use broken out by major areas is periodically
> recorded to the error log. These diagnostic messages can be useful for
> quickly identifying memory resource consumption at a glance and aid in
> determining where to investigate memory-related issues.

[KB: Memory Consumption Logging and Status](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/527/0/memory-consumption-logging-and-status)